# Starting Freelance, how to ask to subcontract for employer

Tags: professionalism, freelancing

**to give some context:**

I am going to transition from employee to self-employed as a freelance software engineering consultant.

I am currently working at a client, the performance review was good, and my contract (with my employer) was extended for a year.
The projects at the client still require work and I would like to finish them before moving on to prevent unneeded handovers and potential knowledge loss and delays.

**The question:**
How do I professionally go about handing in my resignation at my employer, while simultaneously asking to be allowed to stay working at the client, either directly at the client (the confirmed they would renew my contract as a freelancer) or subcontracting via my current employer?

Comment: Be sure you have read and understand any employment agreements or contracts you have signed.  Typically poaching is prohibited.

Comment: Disagree with closing as too broad. This is a relatively narrow and common problem to address, even though there are multiple layers to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't. You hand in your resignation and point out that you would be happy to subcontract for them at any time in the future. I'd be very surprised if your current employer doesn't have a clause in your contract or the one with the current client which explicitly forbids you working for them for the next few months. They will have protected themselves from poaching.

Answer (score 0):

Your employer may see this as unfriendly / illegal competition, or conflict of interests, or something similar - you are "stealing"a customer, a source of income.

Therefore, this question may be better suited to the [Law community](https://law.stackexchange.com/)